# Library for CoverFlow iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, coverflow

I am googling from last two hour. and found many links for CoverFlow. but mostly are not working with iOS 5. and give errors. With many codes I change my compiler settings but it's not work for me.

please provide me tutorial link for Coverflow compatable  with iOS 5 or any open source code.

thanks.

Comment: http://mobiledevelopertips.com/open-source/ios-open-source-icarousel-paging-control.html Regards.

Comment: Which ones have you tried? What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a cover flow implementation in [tapkulibrary](https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary), and another one (with many variants) in [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel), which also has many example projects.

Answer (score 1):

Try this project. It will help you to achieve your motive. http://www.chaosinmotion.com/flowcover.html I implemented it in iOS 5 by not using ARC also by choosing my latest compiler and SDK

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ARC? If so, turn it off and most, if not all of the libraries will compile fine with iOS5.

Comment: thanks for quick reply. yes. i am using ARC. and I also disable ARC. but compiler issues. can you provide me a good link or tutorial?